# AngularJS - Youtube player directive with complete external controls

Tags: angularjs, video, youtube

In my Angular app, I want to use a youtube player to play videos, and then add custom external buttons to control playback. I need a directive that can control all aspects of the video, including seek and progress. The most complete directive I have found is [youtube-player-embed](https://github.com/brandly/angular-youtube-embed), but I don't see any options for seek and progress. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Playback_controls), it is indeed possible to seek and get the player progress. Since the directive `youtube-player-embed` is just a wrapper over the youtube video player object, then you should be able to use the exact same functions calls to control it.

In the page for [advanced examples for youtube-player-embed](http://brandly.github.io/angular-youtube-embed/#/advanced) you can see how they built a player with custom controls, in this case only `Play` and `Pause`, but it should be trivial to follow that example and add a `Seek` button as well.

Good luck!